# Sleeping in Lua Without Prohibiting Previous Command

Tags: timer, lua, delayed-execution

In Lua there is no simple way to sleep for a desired amount of time. To fix this I created a function that does this for me:

```
local clock = os.clock
function sleep(n)  -- seconds
   local t0 = clock()
   while clock() - t0 <= n do
   end
end
```

I then applied it to some code:

```
player:applyLinearImpulse(0, -14, player.x, player.y)
sleep(1)
```

The goal was to apply a linear impulse to the ground then freeze the game. However, this simply freezes the game before applying the impulse. In general how can I make sure the previous command is carried out before I sleep?

Comment: It seems that the `applyLinearImpulse` function takes effect in the next iteration of some main loop, and your `sleep` function prevents you from going back to that main loop. Most event systems/main loops have some form of timers built-in, but we will need to know which event system/main loop you are dealing with to help you adapt your `sleep` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Corona, dynamic actions on objects (like applying an impulse, moving, starting a timer, etc) are really only "enacted" after your code returns. You would have to use `timer.performWithDelay(1, function() sleep(1) end)`.

Once the timer callback is run, the GUI will only be updated upon return from that callback (`sleep`), so your GUI will be frozen during 1 second. That seems to be the effect you are looking for, though usually you don't want to freeze the GUI.